# A doubt over a differentiation problem.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The question is:

> Find the equation of the tangent to the curve $y^2=8x$ at a point $(x_0,y_0)$.

My teacher's approach :

> Differentiate the equation. we get $2y\cdot \dfrac {dy}{dx}=8 $
>
> which gives us : $\dfrac {dy}{dx}=\dfrac4y$.
>
> At a point $(x_0,y_0)$, slope of the tangent =$\dfrac4{y_0}$
>
> So the equation of the tangent is $\dfrac{y-y_0}{x-x_0}=\dfrac4{y_0}$

What bothers me here is the differentiation. According to wikipedia :

> the derivative is the ratio of the infinitesimal change of the output over the infinitesimal change of the input producing that change of output. For a real-valued *function* of a single real variable, the derivative at a point equals the slope of the tangent line to the graph of the *function* at that point.

But, $y^2=8x$ is **NOT** a function. Then, how can one find the derivative?
This bothers me a lot.. Can someone help me? Thank you.

Comment: It is a function, but $x=f(y)$.

Comment: then, shouldnt we find $dx/dy$ instead of $dy/dx$?

Comment: Good question! But don't forget that the slope of the tangent line is computed as the angle between it and the $x$-axis. So if you take $x'=y/4$ you have to invert it.

Comment: You're assuming that the given equation defines $y$ as a function of $x$ "near" the given point. Then  you differentiate both sides of the equation with respect to $x$ (so by the chain rule, ${d\over dx} y^2=2y{dy\over dx}$). This is called "implicit differentiation".

Comment: but, y is *not* a function right?

Comment: What you can do is by knowing what $(x_0,y_0)$ is, you will know on which of the two branches it is (i.e. which of $y = \pm\sqrt{8x}$ it is). By restricting yourself to one of these branches, you will have a function but you are right $y^2 = 8x$ is not a function. Instead it is a relation.

Comment: Take for example the point $(x_0,y_0)=(9,-3)$. There is a unique function $y(x)$, defined for a (generous) interval about $x=9$, such that $y^2=x$. It is is the function usually called $-\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: that's fine, but as @David Mitra pointed out,we're assuming y as a *function* of x "near" the given point. Then you differentiate both sides of the equation with respect to x to obtain $dy/dx$. I find that strange

Comment: sorry if i'm bothering you too much. but $f(x)^2=8x$ is not a *function*, then how can we derive it?

Comment: It may seem trivial for this problem, since you can figure out what $y$ is explicitly (as in André's  comment). For other problems, though, it may be impossible to solve the given equation explicitly for $y$. That's ok, you can  use implicit differentiation to find values of the derivative.

Comment: It is strange, in some sense it is beyond your course, however, it is the custom of first semester calculus to cover said topic. Even though, technically, the justification is only found much later in general (advanced calculus, see the implicit function theorem). However, these sort of logical heresies abound in calculus. For example, we often introduce the Riemann integral without so much as a definition of the convergence of a sequence. But, then in the next semester we berate students for the inability to think subtle thoughts about them. It's not fair. But, it's life.

Comment: I'm deeply intrigued by how it works. I'd love to see the proof. @JamesS.Cook

Comment: @user76849 For this particular problem, Andre Nicolas already told you the proof... you can solve for $y=f_+(x) = \sqrt{8x}$ or $y=f_{-}=-\sqrt{8x}$ depending on the point in question. The place where these glue together, $(0,0)$ is the one place this calculation fails. At $(0,0)$ the tangent to the curve is vertical and consequently falls outside the scope of functions of $x$. For the proof, there are many places, just about every advanced calculus text contains a proof.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about $y$ and start writing $f(x)^2=8x$. Now you do have a function ( it's just a matter of which symbols you are using ).

Derive this function in respect to $x$, in the left side you have $2f '(x)f(x)$, using the chain rule, and in the right side you have $8$. Both sides are equal, so you get $2f '(x)f(x)=8$, therefore $f '(x)=4/f(x)$.

Comment: well, according to me $f(x)^2=8x$ is *NOT* a function. that's what the whole issue was. your answer doesnt answer my query.

Comment: I'm sorry but I disagree, it IS a function. $f(x)$ is the function, coulbe you be more specific about why is not function according to you?

Comment: @user76849 The *left hand side* of the equation is the rule of a function of $x$. So is the right. Since the two functions are equal, so are their derivatives.